# Joomla creating view from com_content - 404 category not found

Tags: php, joomla, http-status-code-404, categories

I followed this post [How to add a new view (and also a new Menu Item Type) to existing joomla 2.5 components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488723/how-to-add-a-new-view-and-also-a-new-menu-item-type-to-existing-joomla-2-5-com) to create a new view to the com_content conpoment in joomla. I have set it up and set up my own names but when I try to access the page I get 404 - category not found. Why is this happening?

Comment: Presumably the category is not being found .. you should debug your code by going step by step and figuring out where the category is needed and why whatever query you are running is failing. No one can answer a question like "why is the category not being found?" without seeing the code that has the bug in it.  Also make sure you explain what it is that you have done to try to debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My controller hade the wrong name. Changin it solved my problem!